# Copy cells in a row and paste every nth cells

Tags: excel, range, paste, vba

I have this couple of excel files that I need to match. Here is the situation.

I got the source file, where the new data is. In this case, the data is at Row 59 and the values (numeric) start at C59 and go horizontally until CB59.
Some values are special and are in bold.
Then I have the other file, (target). The data is at column D, starting at D9 and goes to D675, but values are every 9 cells. (D19,D18,D27, etc.). They match perfectly.

I would like to have a macro to look for the values in the source file and paste ONLY the values in bold.
For example, if I have the values at C59, D59, E59, F59 in source file, the equivalent in target file would be D9, D18, D27, D36, respectively.
However, if only D59 and E59 have the values in bold, then those will be the only ones copied to target file, in this case, only values at D18 and D27 will change.
Also, if copied, it has to be in regular letter, not bold.

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:
Please discard about bold data. I just found I'm looking for all data copied.
I would like to ask for your support to properly paste the values in row 58, from I column to CB column in wbBook2, and paste them in the wbBook1, starting at D36 and every 9th cell.

I tried this code and it pastes the same wbBook2 I58 value on wbBook 1 D36, D45 and D54. Then the rest of the cells every 9th are blank, and suddenly it stops at D243.

ADDING CODE

```
Sub Macroloco_()

Dim wbBook1 As Workbook

Dim wbBook2 As Workbook

Set wbBook1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wbBook2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\reports Sep\week38.xls")

Dim wsSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet2 As Worksheet
Set wsSheet1 = wbBook1.Worksheets("01")
Set wsSheet2 = wbBook2.Worksheets("results")

Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim targetRow As Long
Dim i As Long

targetRow = 36

lastColumn = wsSheet2.Range("CB" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
For i = 58 To lastColumn
wsSheet2.Range("I" & i).Copy
wsSheet1.Range("D" & targetRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

targetRow = targetRow + 9

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried thusfar; StackOverflow is here to collaborate and help with coding issues, not code-for-you.  if you need help getting started, please use the Macro Recorder, inside of the Developer tab.  If you simply need a lead, look into If statements using .font.bold=True

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I just update the post with the code I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

You have the LastColumn looking for the last row.

```
lastColumn = wsSheet2.Range("CB" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
```

Should be

```
With wsSheet2
    lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

---

**Edit:**

My test codE:

```
Sub fdsa()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        j = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        k = 1
        For i = 1 To j
            .Cells(i, 1).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            k = k + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit2:**

I misunderstood when reading.  I was iterating through rows and pasting in rows; you want, similar to translating, to iterate through columns and paste in rows.

Building on my test code, just need to move the i from row to column in the copy line:

```
Sub fdsa()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        j = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        k = 1
        For i = 1 To j
            .Cells(1, i).Copy 'changed to copy the iterating COLUMN
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'Still pastes in every 9th ROW
            k = k + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Make sure to start in the preferred row, e.g. this test code iterates through the columns in Row 1.

Comment: Personal preference to use Cells over Range as I find doing loops and whatnot easier with variables in Cells(r,c)... keeps it standard.

Comment: Hi. I just changed it and still does the same. It goes to copy I58, I59, I60, and so on, instead to go I58, J58, K58...   After that there are blank cells, that's why I'm seeing them in the target file.

Comment: @AlfredS hm... all i can think is that you need to ensure that the value collected is seen as an integer.  I have updated my code to show what I just used to test.

Comment: @AlfredS Sorry, i was misunderstanding.  Change the order... Cells(row, column) is the order, so if you want to iterate through columns, not rows, you change the location of the loop-variable.  Will update my post.  Had I not checked back in, i wouldn't have seen your post about where you were.  If you update in an answer, you need to go to the other person's post and @ tag them to get attention.

Comment: @AlfredS Updated my post.

Comment: Thanks. Last night I realized that too and updated my post, however, I don't know why it was not updated.  It works wonderful.  One last question. I have updated the last code. I'm looking to apply a formula to a selected cells in column H, but it stops after end with.

Comment: @AlfredS  Couple things... Avoid .Select/.Activate as best you can.  You will need to have a specific range of cells selected to apply the formula, not a column.  Try .Range( .Cells(1,"H"), .Cells(LR, "H")).Formula = "" where you need to fill in the LR (last row).  You can do it dynamically, which would be easiest; I will leave that to your Google abilities!  I'm glad my post helped you; please mark as Answer so the question can be closed out and not be indefinitely left open.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot. I will check to try to fix this last constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new one I'm trying, based on the last reply.

It still copies vertically (I58, I59, I60...) instead of horizontally (I58, J58, K58...)

I just changed the references to go to proper columns and cells per source and target file.

I believe j is the one copying the rows instead of columns.
I'm looking to select column H, calculate a formula with D and E and the copy and paste special.

UPDATE
This code works but it stops just as entering last section Columns (H:H)

```
Sub Macroloco_()
Dim wbBook1 As Workbook
Dim wbBook2 As Workbook

Set wbBook1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wbBook2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\reports Sep\week38.xls")

Dim wsSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet2 As Worksheet
Set wsSheet1 = wbBook1.Worksheets("01")
Set wsSheet2 = wbBook2.Worksheets("report")

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
With wsSheet2
    j = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    k = 36
    For i = 9 To j
        .Cells(58, i).Copy
        wsSheet1.Cells(k, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        k = k + 9
    Next i
End With

Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]-RC[-3]"
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("J9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```